# Pyglet- Moving many shapes at once

Tags: python, pyglet, cellular-automata

I am making a langton's ant cellular automata program, and I want the user to be able to pan and zoom.  Right now, I have all my rectangles (grid squares) stored as a dictionary, and to move/zoom, I iterate through all of them and apply the transformation needed.

```
def zoom(self, factor, center_x, center_y):
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        for y in range(HEIGHT):
            rect =  self.rects[x][y]
            self.rects[x][y].x = (rect.x - center_x)*factor + center_x
            self.rects[x][y].y = (rect.y - center_y)*factor + center_y
            self.rects[x][y].width = rect.width * factor
            self.rects[x][y].height = rect.height * factor
```

However, with the amount of rectangles (32,000), it takes a second or to do pan and zoom.  Is there any better way of doing it than this?  Thanks!

[Here](https://github.com/LoneSurvivr314/Langtons-Ant/tree/main) is the full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use OpenGL transformation matrices to apply transformations. These will be calculated on the GPU for performance gain.

[pyglet.graphics.Group](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/graphics/index.html#pyglet.graphics.Group) lets you group together such transformations in order to apply them automatically to Pyglet primitives when drawing them.

### Example

We create a `CameraGroup` that pans and zooms objects into view.

```py
import pyglet.gl as gl
import pyglet.shapes

class CameraGroup(Group):
    def __init__(self, window, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.win = window

    def set_state(self):
        gl.glPushMatrix()
        x = -(self.win.x - self.win.width // 2)
        y = -(self.win.y - self.win.height // 2)
        gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0)
        gl.glScalef(self.win.factor, self.win.factor, 1.0)

    def unset_state(self):
        gl.glPopMatrix()
```

The example assumes you have the properties `center_x`, `center_y` and `factor` on your window.

Apply the group by attaching it to Pyglet objects.

```py
cam_group = CameraGroup(main_win)
rect = pyglet.shapes.Rectangle(250, 300, 400, 200, color=(255, 22, 20), batch=batch, group=cam_group)
```

When `rect` gets rendered the group transformations area applied automatically.

You can also construct more complex groups if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a camera example for pyglet in the examples folder.

https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/blob/pyglet-1.5-maintenance/examples/camera.py